# Not able to return correct value from array filter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the objects from this data array of objects where the `checked` are true in the nested object. Inside the callback function it is returning only those object where `checked` is true

```
{name: "Beginner", skills: Array(1)}
{name: "Intermediate", skills: Array(1)}
{name: "Professional", skills: Array(0)}
```

But when I am returning and logging it it is showing an array of two objects

```
{name: "Beginner", skills: Array(2)}
{name: "Intermediate", skills: Array(2)}
{name: "Professional", skills: Array(2)}
```

I am not able to make out where I am making mistake

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Beginner",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Intermediate",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Professional",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
];


let newData = data.filter(function(item) {
  let dt = {
    name: item.name,
    skills: item.skills.filter(elem => elem.checked)
  }
  console.log(dt)
  return dt
});
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: In your Snippet it runs just fine.

Comment: Your `filter` is just returning everything because you are returning a truth value from it's callback.

Answer (score 2):

try to use map instead of filter

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Beginner",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Intermediate",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Professional",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
];


let newData = data.map(item => {
  return {
   name: item.name,
   skills: item.skills.filter(elem => elem.checked)
  }
});
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce()`

```js
const data = [{"name":"Beginner","skills":[{"name":"Skill 1","checked":false},{"name":"Skill 2","checked":true}]},{"name":"Intermediate","skills":[{"name":"Skill 1","checked":true},{"name":"Skill 2","checked":false}]},{"name":"Professional","skills":[{"name":"Skill 1","checked":false},{"name":"Skill 2","checked":false}]}];

let newData = data.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, {
  name: item.name,
  skills: item.skills.filter(elem => elem.checked)
}], []);

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not filter the array, because you always return a truthy value, which is not the result, but the flag for taking this item.

For filtering, you need to take later the length of the nested array.

```js
const data = [{ name: "Beginner", skills: [{ name: "Skill 1", checked: false }, { name: "Skill 2", checked: true }] }, { name: "Intermediate", skills: [{ name: "Skill 1", checked: true }, { name: "Skill 2", checked: false }] }, { name: "Professional", skills: [{ name: "Skill 1", checked: false }, { name: "Skill 2", checked: false }] }],
    newData = data
        .map(({ name, skills}) => ({ name, skills: skills.filter(({ checked }) => checked) }))
        .filter(({ skills: { length } }) => length)

console.log(newData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```